# Inequality with cardinal numbers

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

I want to check if the following statement holds:

If $a, b, c $ are cardinal numbers and $a<b$ then $a^c<b^c$.

If the statement would hold, given that there is a bijective funcion $f: a \to b$ there will also be a bijective function $g: a^c \to b^c$.

Since $f$ is bijective, we have that $f(a)=b$.

So there will be a $y$ such that $f(a^c)=y$.

Is this right so far? If so, how can we continue?

Comment: The statement is wrong. You have $2 < \aleph_0$. However $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = \mathfrak c$.

Comment: And $a < b$ means that there is an injection $f : a \to b$. Not a bijection.

Comment: How could we show that it holds that $2^{\mathbb{N}_0}=\mathbb{N_0}^{\mathbb{N_0}}$ ? "mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: You have $2 <\aleph_0 <2^{\aleph_0}$. Therefore according to [cardinal arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number#Cardinal_arithmetic) $2^{\aleph_0} \le \aleph_0^{\aleph_0} \le 2^{\aleph_0 \times\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ as $\aleph_0 \times \aleph_0 = \aleph_0$.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I wrote at least one counterexample to this question before on this site.

Comment: But you *can* conclude that $a^c\le b^c$.

Answer (score 5):

Your statement is **false**. For example, $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ and $2^\mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality - put another way, $$(\aleph_0)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}.$$

We can see this by invoking basic cardinal arithmetic rules, as $$2^{\aleph_0}\le (\aleph_0)^{\aleph_0}\le (2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0\times\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0},$$ with the first inequality being trivial, the second following from the *weak* monotonicity of exponentiation (which is also pretty trivial), and the third and fourth following from the definitions of cardinal multiplication and exponentiation (together with a bit of Currying).

However, we can also see this directly via Cantor-Bernstein (which, as a reminder, does *not* require Choice). Namely, fix your favorite [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function) $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:\mathbb{N}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, and given $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ let $\hat{f}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow 2$ be defined by $$\hat{f}(\langle a,b\rangle)=1\quad\iff\quad f(a)=b$$ (and $\hat{f}(\langle a,b\rangle)=0$ otherwise). It's easy to check that the map $$f\mapsto\hat{f}$$ is an injection from $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ to $2^\mathbb{N}$. Since the identity provides an injection the other way, Cantor-Bernstein gives a bijection.

(Incidentally, your "proof" also gets cardinal inequality wrong: "$a<b$" means that there is an injection from $a$ to $b$ but there is not an injection from $b$ to $a$.)

---

It's worth pointing out that increasing the *exponent* doesn't necessarily increase the whole power either: letting $\kappa=2^{\aleph_1}$, we have $$\kappa^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1\times\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_1}\quad\mbox{and}\quad \kappa^{\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1\times\aleph_1}=2^{\aleph_1}.$$ This is indeed the usual situation:

> Operations on cardinals *(including addition, multiplication, and exponentiation)* are very often *weakly* monotonic in each of their arguments but not *strongly* monotonic in any of them.

Comment: *It's worth pointing out that increasing the* exponent *doesn't necessarily increase the whole power either* --- Actually, your earlier example also shows this. Denoting $2^{\aleph_0}$ by $c,$ you showed that $c^1 = c^{\aleph_0}.$ For what it's worth, the fact that $c^{\aleph_0} = c$ has nothing to do with $c$ being too large to increase through exponentiation by $\aleph_0,$ because there exist arbitrarily large cardinals $b$ such that $b < b^{\aleph_0}$ and there exist arbitrarily large cardinals $b$ such that $b = b^{\aleph_0}.$ **(continued)**

Comment: To the proposer: In particular $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}.$

Comment: For strict inequality examples, let $\{a_n\}$ be any strictly increasing sequence of cardinal numbers (e.g. $a_1$ chosen arbitrarily large, $a_2 = 2^{a_1},$ $a_3 = 2^{a_2},$ etc.). Then by Konig's strict inequality lemma for infinite products and infinite sums, and letting $b$ be the sum of the cardinals in the sequence, we have $b$ less than the product of the cardinals in the sequence, which in turn is less than or equal to ${b}^{\aleph_0}$ **(continued)**

Comment: (the last $\leq$ is because $a_n < b$ for each $n,$ hence the product of the $a_n$'s is $\leq$ the product of $\aleph_0$ many $b$'s). For equality examples, let $b = a^{\aleph_0}$ for arbitrarily large cardinals $a.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro That's absolutely true - I just thought that the separate example might help the OP.